# How to display button according to options in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a "choose and reorder" module in which we drag and drop the options if the options are arranged in correct order then it will show button along with it that this is correct(shown in the figure) https://www.screencast.com/t/n8u5M0akkJd

I have made half of the module only button part is left.Can anybody guide me for this?

```
function eval()
{
    $( ".ui_color" ).each(function() {
        var x= $(this).attr('value');

         var y = $(this).parent().children().index(this) + 1;

  if(x==y)
  {
    alert('right')
  }
  else
  {
  alert('wrong');
  }
});
}

 $( function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
          revert: true
        });
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
          connectToSortable: "#sortable",
          helper: "clone",
          revert: "invalid"
        });
        $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
      } );

       $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
          revert: true,

          update: function(event, ui){
            var currentOrder = '1,2,3';
            var sortOrder = [];
            $(event.target).find('li').each(function(){
              sortOrder.push($(this).attr('value')); 
            })
            if(sortOrder.join(',') === currentOrder){
              //alert('correct Answer');
            }else{
              //alert('wrong Answer');
            }
               alert('hi');
               var x= eval();
          }

        });
```

```css
 ul { 
        list-style-type: none; 
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px; 
     }
    .ui_color { 
        margin: 5px; 
        padding: 5px; 
        width: 570px; 
        height: 47px;
        background-color: #46B8DA;
        border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #454545;
    }
    .header
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 569px;
        height: 37px;
        padding: 17px 0 0 11px;
        margin-left: 6px;
    }
    .bottom{
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        border-right: 1px solid;
        padding: 0px 6px 1px 6px;
        margin-right: 7px;
    }
    .tablelike
    {
        height: 450px;
    }
    .full_border
    {
        border: 1px solid #800080;
        width: 592px;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>


            <title>jQuery UI Draggable + Sortable</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script src="jq_assingment.js"></script>

        <body>
            <form name="drag_drop" id="drag_drop" class="full_border">
                <div class="header">
                    <span id="draggable" class="border">Choose & Re-order</span>
                </div>
                <div>   
                    <ul id="sortable" class="tablelike">
                        <li class="ui_color" value="1" correct_seq="">1.Typically a sentence contain a subject and practice.</li>
                        <li class="ui_color" value="2">2.Although it may make little sense taken in isolation out of context.</li>
                        <li class="ui_color" value="3">3.A sentence is a set of words that in principle tells a complete thought,</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
                <div class="">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="bottom">Review</li>
                        <li>Correct answer</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

[image]